# Doctrine_Core::getTable()->findAll() how to specify order?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

When using a `Doctrine_Table` object, is it possible to specify the order of the returned collection when using `findAll()` or `findByWhatever()`?

In the [doc's](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_table.html) I see some stuff about `getOrderByStatement()` and `processOrderBy()` but it isn't clear on how to use them...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can also leave the first array blank

```
  $em->getRepository('BackendDestinyBundle:Destiny')->findBy(array(), array('title'=>'asc'));
```

Comment: Ok my bad, don't cry please just trying to help

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted. Quick, simple and works a treat.

Comment: this is actually better than the query builder (in my opinion), after all, the implementation of ``findAll()`` is a call like this ``findBy(array())`` here's the [source code](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#149-171)

Comment: Thank you! I just used this:

`public function findAll() {
    return $this->findBy(array(), array('name' => 'ASC'));
}`

To quickly overwrite the findAll order returned for a form return of a entity.

Answer (score 13):

You can in fact specify a default order by in your schema:

```
Foo:
  columns:
    ...
  options:
    orderBy: bar DESC
```

Note that when you want to specify a different order, you can still create a query and override the default order by.

Comment: isnt this one only for relations?

Comment: Nope it works for models too, but indeed you can use this trick on relations as well.

Comment: This is not a good idea. Orderbys can be expensive, and you don't want to issue them for EVERY query.

Answer (score 6):

According to Jon Wage you should create a Query in this Case… Found in the [mailing-list](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-users/browse_thread/thread/50f850e51a4befdf?pli=1)

Comment: Ya I figured that might be the only solution, just wasn't sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that i had a statement like this

```
$destinos  = $em->getRepository('BackendDestinyBundle:Destiny')->findAll();
```

finaly I changed it to a CreateQuery statement, it does exactly the same but i can put a OrderBy sentence

```
$destinos  = $em->createQuery("SELECT d FROM BackendDestinyBundle:Destiny d order by d.name")->getResult();
```

Comment: You are talking about Doctrine 2 here, and by the way, this isn't the good way to use Doctrine. Should build a query without writing sql code ... You are loosing all advantage from the ORM here...

Comment: Actually he's using ORM quite good here since it's DQL, not SQL.