# Is there a way to specify a default order for a Doctrine 2 model?

Tags: sorting, doctrine-orm

In Rails (and even in Doctrine < 2, IIRC) you can specify a default order for any model. For example, if you tell Rails to always order your `customer` table by `name`, `Customer.all` will always a list of customers ordered by `name`. It makes an enormous amount of sense.

From what I gather it's not possible to do this in Doctrine 2. Evidently they want you to [create a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124340/doctrine-coregettable-findall-how-to-specify-order) instead.

It would be a very DRY, logical and convenient feature to include, and an outstandingly stupid feature to choose to leave out, it seems to me.

I sincerely hope I'm wrong about this option not existing, and before I cry myself to sleep tonight, I wanted to check to see if maybe Doctrine does actually have a way to specify a default order and I just haven't been able to find it. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Please update your chosen answer, you validated the only one that is totally wrong.

Comment: Done. Only took me 3 years.

Comment: Haha! Better late than never.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Whilst you don't seem to be able to do this for an entire model ala Doctrine 1, you can specify ordering as a notation on the inverse side of a relation:

```
// Entity/Category

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $posts
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="category")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
private $posts;
```

Also, if you're implementing entity manager services such as those in [SonataNewsBundle](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http://knpbundles.com/sonata-project/SonataNewsBundle&ei=fr3xT52CLYjm8QPEv4yXDQ&usg=AFQjCNHfXtX_jnf3etwLwhExLYSCOigxFw), you can specify defaults via optional arguments i.e.

```
class PostManager extends ModelPostManager
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = array('name' => 'asc'))
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository($this->class)->findBy($criteria, $orderBy);
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/17416974/6681 on how to make this more generic and flexible.

Comment: Does this work only using annotation? I can't get this to work using YML

Answer (score 27):

```
$items = $entityManager()->getRepository('Item')->findBy(array(),array('field_to_sort_on'));
```

And of course you can just add a method to the Item repository

```
public function findAllWithDefaultSort()
{
    return $this->findBy(array(),array('default_field_to_sort_on'));
}
```

No real need to make a query in this case.  Keep in mind that D2 focuses on object models with relations.  There are a gazillion active record based alternatives out there.

To answer your question: No.

Comment: Nice - the extra `findBy()` parameter is helpful to know about. Thanks. Unfortunately it's not the same thing as a default order. Neither of these workarounds are nearly as DRY as it would be just to have a default order.

Comment: With this method in Symfony 2.1 I get Unrecognised field: 0 with `->findBy(array(),array('field_to_sort_on'))`.  To fix this it needs the field as the array key and the direction as the array value: `->findBy(array(),array('field_to_sort_on' => 'ASC'))`

Comment: Symfony 2.3.2 doesn't seem to allow functions that start with `findAll...` in repositories (`Undefined method 'findAllWithDefaultSort'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!`)

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel true, but I believe he said to "add a method to the item repository" which would mean that his function "findAllWithDefaultSort" would be a custom function and not a magic function as you're talking about.

Comment: @mason81 Yeah, you're right. I missed that. My bad.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel no worries. :)

Answer (score 24):

I had the same question, I found that overriding the `findAll()` function in your Repository works pretty well:

```
public function findAll()
{
    return $this->findBy(array(), array('lft'=>'asc'));  
}
```

Comment: Very simple and clever solution!

Comment: See my answer below stackoverflow.com/a/17416974/6681 on how to make this more generic and flexible.

Answer (score 11):

A relatively simple way to achieve this is to override the `findBy` method in the Entity's repository class:

```
class MyEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        $orderBy = $orderBy === null ? array('added' => 'desc') : $orderBy;
        return parent::findBy($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);
    }
}
```

This adds a default ordering to all the findBy methods, and allows you to override the ordering if you need to. The same can be done for `findOneBy` if needed.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like no, there is no way to specify a default order in Doctrine 2.

Comment: See my answer on this page. It's relatively simple to implement.

Comment: It looks like this is no longer the correct answer, any chance you can update please.

Answer (score 2):

findBy's parameter 1 is the search criteria, parameter 2 is orderby and seems to need to take either ASC (ascending) or DESC (descending)

```
$accounts = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\User')
                     ->findBy(array('active' => 1), array('email' => 'ASC'));
```